# detachedcriteria and detachedquery without EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one question concerning JPA:
Is there a way to simulate DetachedCriteria (from Hibernate) using the api of JPA 2.0 ?

And if there is a way which classes I need to extend in order to achieve this?

I'm using hibernate 3.6.5 and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In hibernate you create a DetachedCriteria object outside a Hibernate Session and then attach it to a later Session for execution.

In summary - EJB-style JPA EntityManagers (with container-managed PersistenceContext) can create a Query object that automatically behaves similarly to Hibernate DetachedCriteria, but "core java" style EntityManagers (i.e. application managed) can never create Queries that behave similarly to Hibernate DetachedCriteria.

JPA's PersistenceContext is equivalent to a Hibernate Session.
JPA's Query is equivalent to a DetachedCriteria.
A JPA EntityManager may or may not have a PersistenceContext present at any moment.  There are three types of EntityManager:

1. Transaction Context EM - This type of EM can only be created within a SessionBean EJB - @Stateless or @Stateful.  The PC is fully container managed.  When no transaction is executing, the PC is absent.  When a transaction has started and persistence operations occur, the PC is automatically created and attached and propagated with the transaction - each EM operation looks up the PC within the transaction private data.  The PC is automatically cleared and removed when the transaction ends.
2. Extended Context EM - This type of EM also can only be created within a SessionBean EJB - but only a @Stateful.  The PC is also fully container managed.  The PC is created when a bean starts a session conversation (first method called from on a reference to the bean).  The PC is attached to the private data of the Stateful Session Bean.  The PC is cleared and removed when the last method of the session conversation has completed (i.e. a method marked with @Remove is called)
3. Application Managed EM - This type of EM can be created anywhere - in any type of EJB or in any java POJO that has the JPA classes in its classpath.  The PC is created when the EM is created and the PC is cleared and removed when the EM is closed.

Under cases (1) and (2) the EntityManager can create a Query (via em.createQuery() method) at any time.  Later, when a PC exists, the query can be run.  This is identitcal behaviour to Hibernate.  Under case (3) there is no equivalent to Hibernate DetachedCriteria.

Don't be scared by the fact I mentioned EJBs here.  They are trivially easy to implement and are basically just POJOs with some extra annotations added and some App Server functionality invisibly added to make them "bigger, faster, stronger" than POJOs.

An example of (2):

```
@Stateful   
class MyStatelessEJB {    
   // Entity Manager is automatically created and injected     
   // persistent unit name is in persistence.xml
   @PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistenceUnitName",type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)   
   EntityManager em;    
   Query q1 = null;    
   Query q2 = null;

   @NOT_SUPPORTED                                     // no transaction or PC here 
   public methodA() {....                               
                      q1 = em.createQuery(...);       // create query anyway
                      q2 = em.createTypedQuery(...);
                      ...}  

   public methodB() {....  q.execute();  ...}    // transaction & PC here - just use Query

   @Remove   
   // when this method is completes the EJB Session ends    
   public methodC() {....  List<Foo> fooList = q.execute().getResultList; ...} 

}
```

An example of (1) (Stateless Session Bean with Transaction scoped PC) would look similar, but would have no instance variables because it is stateless.  The EntityManager & Query would have to be either created and stored as local variables within each method, or would have to be passed/transferred to another stateful EJB where they could be stored.